# write powershell cmdlet output to a file instead of writing to pipeline from c#

Tags: c#, powershell, redirect, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to implement a powershell cmdlet in C#.

I have an object in the code something like.

```
class A{
    string Title_p;
    string Title_q;
    int Title_r;
    string[] Title_s;
}
```

So, in the cmdlet implementation, when I give `this.WriteObject(A_obj)`, it converts the object data into beautiful readable table format with column titles as object names. Something like below:

```
Title_p   Title_q  Title_r  Title_s
=======   =======  =======  =======
Hello      Bolo     12     {RR,TT,YY}
```

But all this output is redirected to the pipeline where the final cmdlet will be fired from.

But I also want to log all this output to a file (besides printing to pipeline)

I am aware that I can give `CmdLet-Sud | out-file c:/data.txt`. But I don't want this. I want to just fire the command `CmdLet-Sud`, and it should print the data to pipeline as well as to a file.

So, how to convert the object into such a printable table format?

Comment: Pipe it to `Format-Table` prior to `Out-File`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I don't see how piping output to `ft` will result in output to "c:\data.txt". `ft` doesn't even accept a file argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a "Powershell" in your C# code (using System.Management.Automation.Powershell). Your "Powershell" (bad choice of class names IMO, I'll call it SMA.Powershell in this answer for clarity) can invoke `tee-object` (or `append-content` or `set-content`). You can then pass your class instance(s) as arguments to the SMA.Powershell.

Alternatively you can just use classes under the System.IO file space and write the file directly. You can separately write the same output via write-object.

BTW, writing the output to a file doesn't make sense unless you have support for serialization and deserialization in your class. Unless, what you really want is to write your class instance as a textual table. In which case your SMA.Powershell can be something like `% { $_ | ft | set-content c:\data.txt; $_}`.

Comment: tee-object accepts objects of type psObject, but not user class objects. Could you kindly elaborate your idea of using powershell inside c#?

Comment: `tee-object` accepts any kind of powershell object. psobject is just PS's wrapper around an arbitrary .NET object. I'm not sure what you need elaborated.

Comment: Thanks, Tee-Object did the work for me. But only partially. For every invoke() call, the file is creating a header and then the column data. So if i write 3 objects of same kind. there are 3 headers and 3 data columns.

Comment: @Sudheer I answered your question. SO is not about whether the answer can be dropped into your code and expecting your whole script to work. It is about getting the problem you posed solved. If you needed the objects grouped under a single header, then you needed to ask that as part of your original question.

Comment: Absolutely, its not about dropping the answer as a code. But neither the users who search content in stackoverflow expect partial solutions. When I said "I also want to log all this output to a file (besides printing to pipeline)", it means that the objects grouped under a single header. Thats how the data will be printed to pipeline.

Comment: How would someone know "I also want to log all this output to a file (besides printing to pipeline)" means "grouped under a single header"? If you carefully read the help center material and the blogs that are linked to you'll see that answers to questions posing concrete problems is encouraged and expected. But that doesn't mean that the rest of what you consider the solution is included in the answer. Just take this as advice for writing better questions next time (and for editing this question to improve it and add further things you've discovered since you first posted.)

Answer (score 0):

Tee-Object did the work for me.

```
PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
powerShellInstance.AddCommand("Tee-Object");
powerShellInstance.AddParameter("FilePath", filePath);
powerShellInstance.AddParameter("InputObject", obj_A);
powerShellInstance.AddParameter("Append");
powerShellInstance.Invoke();
```

But, when the above code is invoked multiple times, the file is written as

```
Title_p   Title_q  Title_r  Title_s
=======   =======  =======  =======
Hello      Bolo     12     {RR,TT,YY}

Title_p   Title_q  Title_r  Title_s
=======   =======  =======  =======
Aaaao      Colo     13     {EE,YY}

Title_p   Title_q  Title_r  Title_s
=======   =======  =======  =======
HHSAR      Dolo     14     {QQ,XX}
```

But in cmdlet implementation, even though you call this.WriteObject() multiple times with multiple objects, the result would be as

```
Title_p   Title_q  Title_r  Title_s
=======   =======  =======  =======
Hello      Bolo     12     {RR,TT,YY}
Aaaao      Colo     13     {EE,YY}
HHSAR      Dolo     14     {QQ,XX}
```

I am trying to see if I can tweak the code such that even the invoke() command is called multiple times in a program, the output file would still have only only one column header instead of one column header for each object (in the final output file)

Answer (score 0):

Finally done, with want I wanted:

```
// When this method is called for the first time, it creates a table header too.
// The following is the PowerShell line that will be run in the runspace.
// Write-Output -InputObject <object_A> | Format-Table | Out-String

// For the next time, when this routine is called, the following gets executed.
// Write-Output -InputObject <object_A> | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeLine = runspace.CreatePipeline();

Command command1 = new Command("Write-Output");
command1.Parameters.Add("InputObject", object_A);

Command command2 = new Command("Format-Table");
if (this.filePath != null)
{
    // If this is not the first row, hide the table headers
    command2.Parameters.Add("HideTableHeaders");
}
Command command3 = new Command("Out-String");

pipeLine.Commands.Add(command1);
pipeLine.Commands.Add(command2);
pipeLine.Commands.Add(command3);
var results = pipeLine.Invoke();

// The resultant text from the command will have a lot of white spaces/carriage returns.
// So, let us trim the content before adding it to file.
foreach (var result in results)
{
    string data = null;
    data = string.Concat(result);
    data = data.Trim();

    // For the first time, we need to create a log file too.
    if (filePath == null)
    {
        // Call custom routine CreateLogFile() which creates a file and returns the file path as string for you
        filePath = CreateLogFile();
    }

    // Write the object row into the file.
    using (StreamWriter writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(this.filePath))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(data);
    }
}

runspace.Close();
```